Tornado cash hash verification
In tornado cash, a deposit transaction is committed using $TXid = H(nullifier||secret)$. Then, to withdraw, the user has to submit $nullifierHash = H(nullifier)$. The double spending is prevented by maintaining a searchable array of $nullifierHash$.
Q: how is it checked that $nullifierHash = H(nullifier)$ in zero knowledge, i.e. without revealing $nullifier$?
They seem to rely on converting $H(.)$ into a circuit and then they use R1CS https://www.zellic.io/blog/how-does-tornado-cash-work/

The comparison of nullifierHash and H(nullifier) is part of the Withdraw circuit.
https://github.com/tornadocash/tornado-core
https://github.com/tornadocash/tornado-core/blob/master/circuits/withdraw.circom
"signal private" is for the zero-knowledge/concealed elements.

Does that mean knowledge of $\text{nullifier}$ such that $\text{nullifierHash}=H(\text{nullifier})$ is actually verified without disclosing $\text{nullifier}$ ? For what hash function $H$ exactly ?

Yes, and I believe MiMC. https://byt3bit.github.io/primesym/mimc/

Pedersen hash https://tornadoeth.cash/audits/TornadoCash_cryptographic_review_ABDK.pdf This is precisely my question. They rely on Circom as a black box, and I would like a clear first principle explanation how this works. And if it works (for some hash functions) without invoking R1CS, which seems an overkill for Pedersen hash.

That would go into how ZKP in the SNARK context work at all, which is broad and complex. If you want to get some intuition about how some succinct ZKP works at all there is a good toy example: https://starkware.co/stark-101/
